# Queuing an Array Push using PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a problems using 2 array push on same time . When i pushed 10 elements into first array,and 20 elements on the second array, it worked well. But when i pushed 1000 elements on first array, the second array won't push.. 
Here is my code :

```
public function save() {
   extract($_POST);

   $first_array  = array();
   $second_array = array();

   // This array contains 1000 elements to push
   foreach($data as $key) {

     $data3 = array(
        'LOCATION_ID'   => $key,
        'TRX_ID'        => $id,
     );
     array_push($first_array,$data3);
   }

   // This array contains 20 data
   for($i = 0; $i < $total ; $i++) {
      $data4 = array(
        'CONDITION' => $CONDITION[$i],
        'TRX_ID'    => $id
      );
      array_push($second_array,$data4);
   }
   $insert_first  = $this->db->insert_batch('LOCATION',$first_array);
   $insert_second = $this->db->insert_batch('CONDITION',$second_array);

   if($insert_first) {
      if($insert_second) {
        $message = array(true,'success');
      } else {
        $message = array(false,'failed');
      }
   } else {
        $message = array(false,'failed');
   }
   echo json_encode($message);
}
```

```
 <form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/transaction/save">

   <div class="form-group">
     <label>Location</label>
     <select name="LOCATION[]" multiple class="form-control">
        <?php foreach($LOC as $key) : ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $key['id_location'] ?>"><?php echo $key['location_name'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
     </select>
   </div>

   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="total" value="<?php echo count($CON); ?>">

   <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>VALUE</th>
          </tr>
        <thead>
        <tbody>
           <?php $no = 1; foreach($CON as $value) : ?>
               <tr>
                 <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $value['condition_name'] ?></td>
                 <td><input type="number" name="CONDITION<?php echo $no; ?>"></td>
               </tr>
           <?php $no++ ;endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>

 </form>
```

Is there any way to queuing both array ? i already tried move the position of the array push. So the second array pushing first , then the first array on the second push. Any kind of help is really appriciated, Thank you..

Comment: Where is `$total` which controls your second loop set?

Comment: $total is from view , extracted from extract($_POST); , also $id...@NigelRen

Comment: Could it be a memory issue? Sometimes PHP silently fails.

Comment: That's another problem i wouldn't think of... @JohannesSchidlowski

Comment: @BaktiWijaya where is `$id`, `$total`, and `$CONDITION` ?

Comment: it's extracted from the form, using extract($_POST) @HastaDhana

Comment: if you are populating the array based on `POST` input, you may be facing a somewhat obscure limit. `php.ini` has a setting that limits the number of posted fields it'll handle (all posted fields, including hidden fields, count towards the limit). Try changing `max_input_vars` to a number larger than its default of 1000 and you'll be on your way

Comment: FWIW, the above was introduced with PHP version 5.3.9, so if you are on any PHP version above that (and you should) this limit will be enforced until you change it

Answer (score 0):

PHP, since version 5.3.9 has a nice little feature that limits the size (measured in number of input variables) of `POST` requests that defaults to 1000. Anything above that is ignored by PHP (and thus by codeigniter)

If you need to post more than 1000 variables (or think you may need to do so in the future) you need to change, in your `php.ini`, the value of the `max_input_vars` variable. Like I said, the default value is 1000 so change it according to your needs.

Even on PHP versions newer than 5.3.9 you may find that the `max_input_vars` directive is not found on the `php.ini`. Don't get misled by the fact that it isn't there, as it will default to 1000 anyway. Just create it :)